# not working web sql on ipad ios 7

Tags: html, ios7, local-storage

I have a web site that uses a web sql (html5). And it works well in ios 6
but after upgrading to ios 7.0.2 it stopped working.
No code changes.

```
var db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
if(!db){alert("Failed to connect to database.");}
```

everything is good, it means safari support html5 web sql db

```
db.transaction(function (transaction) {
transaction.executeSql("CREATE TABLE user_info (user_first_name TEXT, user_last_name TEXT)", null, null, TransactionError);
```

error "1 not authorized"

```
transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO user_info (user_first_name, user_last_name) VALUES (?, ?)",[FirstName, LastName], _transactionCallBack, TransactionError);});
```

error "1 no such table user_info"

I do not understand what has changed during the upgrade on ios 7.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Apple Developer Relation

Engineering has determined that your bug report is a duplicate of another issue and will be closed. 

The open or closed status of the original bug report your issue was duplicated to appears in the yellow "Duplicate of XXXXXXXX" section of the bug reporter user interface. This section appears near the top of the right column's bug detail view just under the bug number, title, state, product and rank.
Example:

User interface anomaly in OS X
                  
State: Duplicate                   Product: OS X
Rank: 3 - Medium
Duplicate of 10535951 (Open)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figgured it out.When you enter safari, a little button on the top left on the keyboard says "private", click it to disable it. The database will work fine. But! jquery mobile will not be able to use the back button. For this, you have to delete appcache from your code. jquerymobile 1.4 will fix this, but for now you will have to live without appcache!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I installed another browser google chrome for ios.
and everything works fine.

Comment: Glad I could help. Never thought of installing Chrome, nice tip!

Comment: Using your help I'm still not able to work with websql in safary ((

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Have you disabled private browsing? What happens then? Whar error message do you get?

Comment: This was driving me nuts -- the `could not prepare statement (1 not authorized)` message in doing the simplest operation (creating a table). Indeed my Safari browser was set to Private browsing mode.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of this, apple really needs to change the interface of "private" black browser chrome is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

This is knowing issue on ios7, if you request more than 5mb of dbsize, it will not work. Details you can reference this post http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review